# Homophonic Substitution Cipher Python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to make a homophonic substitution cipher, where the most common letters are substituted by multiple other symbols, For example, if my plaintext was "EEEEEEE" The E would be replaced with several different symbols, which in this code would be "%" and "-"

What I have now is this

```
def encryption():
    plaintext = "EEEEEEE"
    plaintext = plaintext.replace("E", "%" "-")
    print(plaintext)
encryption()
```

I'm intending for the ciphertext to look something like this "%--%-%-", where the letter E would be replaced randomly by the 2 symbols I chose, but what ends up happening is that I get "%-%-%-%-%-%-%-", which replaces every individual E with all the symbols, therefore giving 14 characters instead of the original 7.

I've also tried using the random module but I ended up getting either "%%%%%%%" or  "-------" half the time, but never using both symbols randomly in the same try.

So how would I be able to make my code able to replace every individual E randomly with a "%" and "-"?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to iterate over the string to achieve that kind of randomness.

```
import random
def encryption(plaintext):
  ret = ""
  for i in range(len(plaintext)):
    ret += ("%" if random.random() > 0.5 and (plaintext[i] in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]) else "-")
  return ret
```

Comment: You can't assign to string elements like that.